# How to add a value in a json subarray with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, foreach

How to add a value in a json subarray with jQuery ?

I has build this code but it dosen't work... The developer console tell me "Cannot call method 'push' of undefined"

```
function save(){
    var Arguments = [];
    $('.builder-page').each(function(){
        var title = $(this).find('input[name=title]').val();
        Arguments.pages.push({'title':title})
    });
    console.log(Arguments);
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare it as on object which has an array as its `pages` property.

```
var Arguments = {pages: []};
```

Answer (score 1):

`Arguments` is your array not `pages`. There's no indication in your code that pages is every created...